# unable to convert the dates type data from object to integer

Tags: python, data-science

i am trying to convert the dates whose data type is object and converting them into type integer but unable to convert it using pd.to_numeric

```
import json
import pandas as pd
url='https://api.covid19india.org/states_daily.json'
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'data.json') 
with open('data.json') as f:
data=json.load(f)
data=data['states_daily']
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) 
df.drop('tt', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df = df[df['status'] == 'Confirmed']
df.drop('status', axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
df = df.rolling(7).mean()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there mjght some columns which are not of numerical type hence cancelling the operation, you should able to workaround this by using `errors='ignore'`.

`df  = df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='ignore')`